# Return value of low-level calls not used

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm attempting to use the function `send()` in Solidity 
I've got this error when i try to compile my contract with truffle :

> Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used.

any idea about it?

thank you

Comment: Abdelalah try to share your code or a snippet in order to figure out the problem.

Comment: just check for the return value of the function call. it will return 0 or 1depending upon the failure or success of the function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use a modifier :

```
modifier send_it(uint _amount, address _address ) {
    if (msg.value < _amount)
        throw;
    _
    if (msg.value > _amount)
        _address .send(_amount - msg.value);
}

  function x(address _newOwner)
        send_it(200 ether,msg.sender) //exemple
    {
     
     }
```

or you could just use simple checking (throw if send failed for some reason):

```
if (_address.send())
 throw;
```

---

Answer (score 8):

It is because your code is not checking the return status from the `send(...)` function:

Using this code below in Solidity Online:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    function testit(address a) {
        a.send(123);
    }
}
```

I get the the following warning message: `Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used.`.

Using the code below instead will remove the warning:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    function testit(address a) {
        if (!a.send(123))
            throw;
    }
}
```

The compiler is warning you to check the return status of the `send(...)` function. Solution - check the return status. This is one of the recommendations on smart contract best practices after the USD 50 million The DAO hack.

Further reference - [Ethereum Contract Security Techniques and Tips](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Safety).

Answer (score 2):

In solidity version 0.5.0 they have made breaking changes and returns bool and bytes. [Reference is here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html).

So you have to use:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = otherContract.send("f")
```

to get the return values and then use it accordingly.